# FTP Upload directory tree in java

Tags: java, ftp, tree

Is there any library that supports uploading directory tree in remote server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Apache Virtual File System](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/index.html) (VFS) project can do this, whilst abstracting the details of dealing directly with FTP connections.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` client and recursively upload all files in your directory.