# Java - Upload folder via FTP?

Tags: java, file, upload, ftp, directory

How do I upload a whole folder via FTP through Java?

I keep on finding how to upload an individual file, but not a whole folder that contains directories and files..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838576/ftp-upload-directory-tree-in-java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ftp a whole folder, look into the `mput` command of FTP.

Any half-decent FTP client implemented in Java will support the `mput` FTP command.